# Android How to solve the calling the web services again and again for more same information utility?

Tags: android, json, web-services, api

Hi I am new in Android Development. I am using some webservices like login. But i not getting how to make webservice call first time then use get data again and again. like first time profile picture load then send time its not need to load from web service. How can i do this for more flexible and less call webservice. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if AsyncTask Already running then you can terminate request check code below

```
 private void doLogin(String id, String pass) {
    if (mLoginAsync != null &&
            mLoginAsync.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.PENDING
            || mLoginAsync.getStatus() == AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
        Log.i(getClass().getName(), "Already Running");
        return;
    }
    mLoginAsync = new LoginAsync();
    mLoginAsync.execute();

}


public class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
        //Write Your api call here
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: bt where is previous data ?

Answer (score 0):

1.Generate a md5 for the data and save it in sharedpreferences(also in server too.)
2.save the data in local db or in sharedpreferences for the first time,For the image use cache technique
3.the next time you call get data call webservice to check for change in md5 i server, if changed then update the data from server to app, otherwise use the data which u saved in step 2.

Answer (score 0):

Write the object in local database:

Step 1 : Parse the data which you get in form of json or xml and serialize it :

```
public static byte[] serialize(Object O) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
    out.writeObject(O);
    out.close();

    // Get the bytes of the serialized object
    byte[] buf = bos.toByteArray();
    return buf;
}
```

Step 2: Create a class and extend SQLiteOpenHelper.
Create table and add the serialized data with the url and type :

```
Class LocalDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
```

@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

```
    db.execSQL(DICTIONARY_TABLE_CREATE);
}
```

public void addQuery(String type, String url, byte [] object) {

```
    this.getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteDatabase db = null;

    try {
        db = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(
                DB,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE, null);

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(URL, url);
        values.put(OBJECT, object);
        values.put(TYPE, type);


        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(CACHE_TABLE_NAME, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
        this.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printstacktrace();
        try {
            db.close();
            this.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printstacktrace();
            this.close();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Step 3: While hitting the url again deserialize the data

public static Object deserialize(byte[] input, String Type) throws        IOException {
    if(Type == abc){
        MyObj obj = (Myob) in.readObject();
        return obj;
      }
}

We can also add time to live param if we want to keep this cache for a particular time period